# Django: how do you deal with queries that can not scale?

Tags: python, django, django-models

In my code, I have a few queries that are not scalable at all.

For example, take a look at this code:

```
class OrderQuerySet(query.QuerySet):
    def for_day(self, day: date):
        """ Return all orders that concerns the given service day """

        day_order_pks = [order.pk for order in self.all()
                         if localdate(order.service.start) == day]
        return self.filter(pk__in=day_order_pks)
```

At the beginning, it perfectly worked.
The problem is, when order amount increase, the performance seems to decreases in a linear way, which makes senses because all orders need to be tested each time. Having 1000 new orders every day, it's obvious my system will not be usable anymore in a few time!

Usually, how do you deal with this kind of problem in Django?

I mean, sometimes I can find a trick to write a better query, using Django ORM only. But sometimes, to get what I want, I seems to be forced to create my queryset this way, using Python and a for loop.

Comment: What is `localdate(..)` doing here? Typicaly such filters can be moved to the database side, making it way more efficient.

Comment: Why do you think you are forced to loop in Python? That should rarely or never be the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please *don't* enumerate over `.all()` unless you *absolutely* have to. It is more efficient to do filtering at the database side. Given `localdate(..)` does not do much, except extracting the date from a `datetime`, you can filter with:

```
class OrderQuerySet(query.QuerySet):

    def for_day(self, day: date):
        """ Return all orders that concerns the given service day """
        return self.filter(service__start__date=day)
```

If `localdate(..)` is more advanced, you can still try to do most of the work at the database side. For example by filtering the queryset down to orders that are within for example 24 hours of the given `date`, and then do advanced filtering at the Python/Django side. But the idea is to do as much as possible at the database side (unless you make some exotic queries that do not scale well at the database, but that is quite rare).

Comment: You answer makes lots of sense. You and @Daniel Roseman are telling that I can (almost) always do filtering at the database level, instead of looping in Python. This means I probably have a lack of knowledge about how to make some advanced filtering in Django. In addition, another of my problem is that lots of my methods take a Python List of Django objects in parameter, instead of a queryset.

Comment: @DavidD.: I think it can pay off to make queryset variants, since filtering, annotating, joining, etc. at database are typically more efficient. In fact one of the main tasks of a database is to filter, join, etc. Note that a queryset is iterable, so some of your methods might already work on querysets.

Comment: I'll do it thanks guys. To be sure, am I on the right way doing this for example? https://www.dropbox.com/s/sykfrqt3f2vqkz6/Screenshot%202019-01-22%2013.24.32.png?dl=0